# python df2gspread.d2g.upload: How can I upload datefram column with data type integer

Tags: python, dataframe, google-sheets-api

is there any way I can use the d2g upload data frame without change all the data type to string?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs17J.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgXfW.png)

the data type changed when I uploaded it to google sheet, how can I keep the original data type.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Answer (score -1):

I got the exact same problem. You should try using gspread-pandas instead. In my experience it works a lot faster than d2g. The installation guide is [here](https://pypi.org/project/gspread-pandas/)

First, you should put your credentials file in the right directory. If you don't know where it is, you can try this

```
from gspread_pandas import Spread
x= Spread(work_sheet_id, worksheet_name)
```

An error message will show up and tell you where the directory is and that you should rename your credentials as google_secret.json and put it there.

After that you can upload into an existing sheet or create a new one:

```
x.df_to_sheet(df, index=False, sheet=worksheet_name, replace=True)
```

The documentation is [here](https://gspread-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gspread_pandas.html#gspread_pandas.spread.Spread.df_to_sheet) if you want to find out more about what parameter values you should use.